# No Windows support for Nidium?

Tags: mobile

when can we expect a Windows instance of Nidium? I use a Windows machine for dev. I see only Linux and OSX are supported currently.

Also, how are you bridging native APIs? Cordova?

Comment: You should address this sort of question to that product's support team/forums/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Nidium co-author here. The windows version is actually on his way (https://github.com/nidium/Nidium/tree/windows-x86). There is still some work to be done before a public release, but the first results are here :)

[image: nidium running on windows]

Regarding native APIs calls, we are not using cordova or anything similar. If needed, you can build you own native module (C++ for desktop computers, or Java/ObjectiveC for Android/iOS).

If you have more questions regarding nidium, check-out our [new website](http://www.nidium.com) or reach us on [IRC](http://irc://irc.freenode.net/nidium) or [Discord](https://discord.gg/h3NqJ9k)

Comment: No native API? Then what's your value-add? What are you offering me or other developers over Nativescript or React Native, Tabris or Tatanium?